# why scala mutable.LinearSeq can not do +=:

Tags: scala

`mutable.MutableList[A]` can do the inline prepend with its `+=:`, but it's trait `mutable.LinearSeq` can not do this. I think the whole purpose of mutable package is for doing inline update in the collection, so why `mutable.LinearSeq` can not prepend?  and what's diff between `ListBuffer` and `MutableList`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why `mutable.LinearSeq` can not prepend?

Prepend (`+=:`) isn't defined on `mutable.LinearSeq`, it's defined on the `BufferLike` trait, which `ListBuffer` extends. `MutableList` doesn't implement the `Buffer` trait, but did choose to provide a prepend method.

A mutable collection is meant for you to be able to mutate it without allocating a new collection, and that is what mutable stands for. Most mutable collection will expose an `+=` method to append values, but it isn't necessary for all to be able to prepend elements in to their underlying collection, that is implementation specific. Depending on the implementation, `+=` can either choose to append an element or prepend it to the underlying collection, depending on how it's storing its values.

> What's diff between `ListBuffer` and `MutableList`?

One of the main differences between `ListBuffer[A]` and `MutableList[A]` is that the former uses lists as the underlying implementation and has O(1) for creating a `List[A]` from the buffer where the latter uses a `LinkedList[A]` for the underlying implementation and is the actual basis for the `Queue[A]` implementation in Scala.